# what is a properly way to change an access of google blob

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I work with Google Storage API via java and I use `0.9.4-alpha`(before was `0.9.2-alpha` ) version of GSAPI.
When I create a blob, I use this code:

```
 bucket.create(
            getFileName(req),
            fileToInputStream(req),
            Bucket.BlobWriteOption.predefinedAcl(getPredefinedAcl(req.getAccessType()))
    );
```

and it works correctly, I have an opportunity to change PredefinedAcl. But if I try to execute this:

```
blob.update(Storage.BlobTargetOption.predefinedAcl(Storage.PredefinedAcl.PRIVATE));
```

I will have an exception `com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Cannot provide both a predefinedAcl and access controls.` and receive the message:

```
 {
         "code" : 409,
         "errors" : [ {
         "domain" : "global",
         "message" : "Cannot provide both a predefinedAcl and access controls.",
         "reason" : "conflict"
         } ],
         "message" : "Cannot provide both a predefinedAcl and access controls."
 }
```

I didn't find anything about this issue.
I'd like to know , what is the true way to update an access? I saw Acl class and all related with it, but I'm not sure that it is that I want, because I need to be able change public/private particular files for all users

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution about how to change an access to files.
For all users it seems this:

```
Acl acl = Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER);
blob.createAcl(acl);  // public for all
blob.deleteAcl(acl.getEntity());  // private for all
```

This code shows how to give a public access for all users and then make files are private from them.